# Adding multiple transistors to increase the output power of an amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I have a Sony amplifier 500 watts I like to increase the out put power to 1000 watts if I add more transistors will it work. How practical is this can this be done. Thank you

Comment: Where do you suppose the extra power is going to come from?

Comment: Just adding more transistors is kind of like making your car transmission beefier and expecting the car to be more powerful. It will only allow your car to handle more power, but that power actually comes from the engine so then you also actually need to make your engine bigger. In other words, you also need to make your audio power supply bigger inside your amp bigger as well.

Comment: I don't know that is why I asked the question

Comment: @lima: I'm encouraging you to think. The power has to come from the power supply. Do you think Sony will have built in a power supply capable of twice the power that was needed?

Comment: @Transistor: I think we can reverse engineer it replace the Sony power supply with the required VDC

Comment: The short answer for just about any commercial amplifier is that by the time you've done all the work necessary to hot-rod your amplifier, you may as well build your own.  There are certainly resources out there for people wanting to DIY their own audio amps.

Comment: Also note that doubling the power might simply **not be worth the trouble**. A common misconception is that doubling the power will make the the amp + speakers go twice as loud. It does not. You need multiply the power by a factor **10** for that! So in your case **5000 W**. See: https://jlaudio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217201737-Doubling-Power-vs-Doubling-Output  What would help much more is **getting more efficient speakers**.

Comment: @TimWescott: So the better approach is to build my own amplifier from scratch

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: So the better approach is to build my own amplifier from scratch

Comment: *So the better approach is to build my own amplifier from scratch* I never said that! I said that the better approach would be to get **better speakers**. If you need the sound to be "louder" then get more speakers and more amplifiers. Putting all power in only one amplifier is less efficient. Go see what the professionals do at concerts, discos theaters etc. Do they use one big amplifier or many smaller ones? Another reason why having more amplifiers instead of one is that if one breaks. If you have 5 and one breaks: no big deal. If you have one and it breaks: no sound.

Comment: If you want more power to the speakers, flowing through electronics that you were responsible for, yes.  Otherwise, what @Bimpelrekkie said.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest can and does work .If you double up the output transistors ensuring that they share with for example seperate emitter resisters ,Then you can expect double the power into half the load resistance .Remember that your power supply voltage is the same but the amplifier puts out twice the current.The power supply will draw twice the current so it must be beefed up too .This has been done on commercial gear where the normal Amp is specified for 4 ohm load and the higher power version with paralleled output transistors is specified down to 2 ohm load .Very high power speakers are hard to find and they have not made 2 ohm speakers since the valve days .Common speakers these days are 4 or 8 ohm so such an Amplifier could run two 4 ohm or four 8 ohm speakers in parallel.

Comment: So the better approach is to build my own amplifier from scratch

Comment: Why not build from scratch .You will learn heaps and you can sell your existing Amp when you are done .